# `.iloc()` returns strange results when used with dask dataframe groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, dask

I have a large dataset with 3 columns:

```
   sku   center units
0   103896  1   2.0
1   103896  1   0.0
2   103896  1   5.0
3   103896  1   0.0
4   103896  1   7.0
5   103896  1   0
```

And I need to use a `groupby-apply`.

```
def function_a(x):
    return np.sum((x > 0).iloc[::-1].cumsum() == 0)

def function_b(x):
    return x.eq(0).sum()/((x.eq(0)&x.shift().ne(0)).sum())
```

Using dask (`df.groupby(['sku', 'center'])['units'].apply(function_a), meta=(float)`), I have many problems applying the first function because dask does not support index operations (`.iloc`), and the results are totally wrong.

Is it possible to apply those function using pyspark UDF ?

Comment: You can use the same functions as a [`pandas_udf` GROUPED_AGG](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/udf-python-pandas.html#grouped-aggregate-udfs)

Comment: How can you be sure that the rows of your group by element are sorted when using dask? Because a different order of your rows/entries for `'units'` would give you a different result on `.cumsum()`?

Comment: Every group ['sku', 'center'] are sorted by descending date. But it seems that it shuffles when I use iloc function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assumptions

Your index (in the above example (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)) corresponds to the correct sorting that you want. E.g. by the data being CSVs of the form

```
0,103896,1,2.0
1,103896,1,0.0
2,103896,1,5.0
```

where the first columns corresponds the sample number. When you then read the data with:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
df = dd.read_csv('path/to/data_*.csv', header=None)
df.columns = ['id', 'sku', 'center', 'units']
df = df.set_index('id')
```

this gives you a deterministic DataFrame. Meaning the index of the data is the same, no matter in what order the data is read from the drive.

### Solution to `.iloc()` problem

You can then change `function_a(x):` to:

```
def function_a(x):
    return np.sum((x.sort_index(ascending=False) > 0).cumsum() == 0)
```

which should now work with

```
df.groupby(['sku', 'center'])['units'].apply(function_a, meta=(float))
```